# iPhone 6: Unable to find service and only displays "Searching"

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 6 with the most recent iOS software installed. Recently (about 2 weeks ago) it started struggling to find mobile connection, while family on the same network get great connection. Wi-Fi and Bluetooth still work fine, so I am unsure as to whether it's a hardware or a software problem.

Can it be fixed or do I need a new phone?

Comment: Do a full reset (obviously back it up, first).  If the problem doesn't go away, it's a hardware issue.

Comment: First step would be to make sure that your cellular connection is active. Try plugging-in the SIM card into another phone and ensure if it is working. If it isn't, try contacting your service provider. To check if the hardware of your iPhone isn't faulty, try plugging in a working SIM card into your iPhone to verify.

Comment: I fixed a similar issue recently with a new SIM card from my provider. Never thought about it before, but apparently they get old, tired & out of date on the firmware side.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to put the phone in airport mode then back to normal and see if that helps.  Next try to reset network connections under general and reset then reset network connections.  you can also try toggling cellular data on/off and/or roaming voice data&data and data roaming on/off.